# How to Add incremental offer based on quantity and predefined offer

Tags: php, mysql

I've a question and stuck on this stage.
As per the attached image, Offer needs to be updated automatically based on item code and its quantity.

Let's say : Item Code (1) has an offer (in offers table) for quantity 12.
(which means when item_code=1 and quantity=12, the offer column will be filled with value 1)

now the hard part is :

1. if quantity is less than 12, 0 for offer column
2. if quantity is equal to 12 and less than 24, offer value will be 1
3. if quantity is equal to 24 or greater but below 36, then offer value will be 2 and so on

Order Form Sample

[image]

I've offers table, in which looks like

```
item_code | quantity | offer
----------|----------|------
1         | 12       | 1
2         | 5        | 1
3         | 8        | 1
```

Any help and guidance is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Further Explanation:
When I enter item_code (1) and quantity (12), it auto inserts offer from (offers) table. I mean the offer is dependent on item_code and quantity. everything is fine at that point.

Real problem occurs when quantity is changed. 
(e.g. item_code=1, quantity=12, offer=1 is fixed and fetched from offers_table based on item_code and quantity values, but when quantity is updated manually, the offer value need to be incremented respectively.

I am trying to create a point_of_sale and not working in PhpMyAdmin. I am working in a web based front end environment. I have initial offer values for items and quantities, it's like buy two and get one free type thing. and if someone buys 4 he should get two free, if 6 then 4 will be free etc.
There are plenty of items and each item has different quantity bar to be eligible for offer. for example
item_code 1 will have one free item when quantity is 12.
item_code 2 will have one free item when quantity is 5.
but when user changes quantity i.e. 24 instead of 12 and 10 instead of 5, the free products should be doubled.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript solution

If you want to do it on the client side, you can do like the following:

```js
var quantityInput = document.getElementById("quantity");
var offerInput = document.getElementById("offer");

var offerFloors = [0, 12, 24, 36];

function updateOffer() {
  var offerValue = 0;
  var quantity = quantityInput.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < offerFloors.length; i++) {
    if (quantity > offerFloors[i]) {
      offerValue = i;
    }
  }
  offerInput.value = offerValue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <input id="quantity" type="number" onChange="updateOffer()"/>
  <input id="offer" type="number"/>
</html>
```

The offer input will be updated on every quantity input changes.

## SQL solution

If you're willing to do it server side, you can do like the followings:

### Simple one

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_update_offer BEFORE UPDATE
ON Offer FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.quantity < 12 THEN
        SET NEW.offer = 0;
    ELSEIF NEW.quantity >= 12 AND NEW.quantity < 24 THEN
        SET NEW.offer = 1;
    ELSEIF NEW.quantity >= 24 AND NEW.quantity < 36 THEN
        SET NEW.offer = 2;
    END IF;
END
```

It's a trigger, it will be called every time you update any row of your table and set the offer column depending on new value of quantity.

### More advanced one

You can automate this behavior by creating a table of offer codes:

```
offer_code | floor
-----------|------
0          | 0
1          | 12
2          | 24
3          | 36
```

And your trigger would then look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_update_offer BEFORE UPDATE
ON Offer FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE offer_code, v_offer_code, v_floor INT;
    DEClARE row_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT offer_code, floor FROM offer_codes;

    OPEN row_cursor;

    get_offer_code: LOOP
        FETCH row_cursor INTO v_offer_code, v_floor ;
        IF NEW.quantity > v_floor THEN
            SET offer_code = v_offer_code;
        END IF;
    END LOOP get_offer_code;

    SET NEW.offer = offer_code;

    CLOSE row_cursor;
END
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, i appreciate that, but it doesn't solve my issue. let me explain it further. When I enter item_code (1) and quantity (12), it auto inserts offer from (offers) table. I mean the offer is dependent on item_code and quantity. everything is fine at that point. Real problem occurs when quantity is changed. (i.e. item_code=1, quantity=12, offer=1 is fixed and fetched from offers_table, but when quantity is updated manually, the offer value need to be incremented.

Comment: When you say "quantity is updated manually", you mean in PhpMyAdmin or a tool like that? You're not doing the update through queries?

Comment: I am trying to create a point_of_sale and not working in PhpMyAdmin. I am working in a web based front end environment. I have initial offer values for items and quantities, it's like buy two and get one free type thing. and if someone buys 4 he should get two free, if 6 then 4 will be free etc

Comment: What i think is, it should be done via ajax+php or javascript+php on frontend part, so offer gets updated instantly before submitting the order form

Comment: Could you post the code of your form? It will be easier to work on it.